# Create classpath from existing jars in a Folder

Tags: python, linux, jython, wsadmin

I new to Python and am looking for a way to create my `CLASSPATH` argument for Jython script in wsadmin for Websphere, by reading from a folder and including all jars in that folder.

**Example** :

```
/jar_dir
    1.jar
    2.jar
    ...
    70.jar

CLASSPATH= INSTALL_PATH + "/jar_dir/1.jar;" + INSTALL_PATH + "/jar_dir/2.jar;"  .... INSTALL_PATH + "/jar_dir/70.jar;"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: try  "/jar_dir/*.jar"?  Not sure if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I would do

```
import glob
```

...

```
";".join(glob.glob(INSTALL_PATH+"/jar_dir/*.jar"))
```

Comment: This worked... But i came acroos an issue. I have to keep the order of few jars. Right now its setting as I wanted but I don't want to take any risk. Any ideas ?

Comment: the problem there is no way to know which order keep except if it is alphabetic or by time creation

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this would be:
[1]
Adding the jars to "com.ibm.ws.scripting.classpath" to your wsadmin.properties file.
See [This.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_propscript.html?cp=SSAW57_8.0.0%2F1-16-2-23&lang=en)

[2]
Or add the switch "-wsadmin_classpath /path/to/jar" when you call wsadmin.